# Kafka Brokers - Log Retention Issue in Windows - Is there any temporary workaround?

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I am running 3 nodes Kafka cluster on Windows Server 2019. I have set the default retention time to 72 hours.
All was working fine for some days but once in a while, I am getting the following exception which causes the Kafka Broker shutting down.

```
Line 3607: [2020-03-15 07:45:24,047] ERROR Error while deleting segments for kafka-monitor-topic-0 in dir E:\uhx\kafka\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
Line 3653: [2020-03-15 07:45:24,047] ERROR Uncaught exception in scheduled task 'kafka-log-retention' (kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler)

Line 3707: [2020-03-15 07:45:24,094] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in E:\kafka\kafka-logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
Line 4187: [2020-03-15 07:45:37,149] ERROR [Log partition=test-0, dir=E:\uhx\kafka\kafka-logs] Could not find offset index file corresponding to log file E:\kafka\kafka-logs\test-0\00000000000000000001.log, recovering segment and rebuilding index files... (kafka.log.Log)

java.nio.file.FileSystemException: E:\kafka\kafka-logs\test-2\00000000000000000000.index -> E:\kafka\kafka-logs\test-2\00000000000000000000.index.deleted: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

When I searched for it, I got to know it is already in the Open Jira issues of Kafka https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194 
But now I need to know if there is any workaround to handle this situation and also clear the logs without the retention policy of Kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround would be to install HyperV and run Kafka there as a Linux process

Other solutions include Docker or buying new servers

Fact of the matter is that there's no workaround for Windows file management until the ticket is addressed

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but due to some requirements we need to use it on Windows only.

Comment: What kind of requirements? The first few options I said are both using Windows